# PHP - Add strings to a XML file with a form

Tags: php

I'm trying using a form to add strings to a XML file but I'm probably missing something, can you help me finding the error? This is the index.php sample:

```
<form action="feedhandler.php" method="POST">
    <input name="link" type="text" placeholder="Enter URL here."/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Import">
</form>
```

and this is the feedhandler.php:

```
<?php

$url = substr($link, strpos($link,'?')+1);
$title = array();
parse_str($url, $title);

$addMe = "<item>
    <title>$title</title>
    <link>$url</link>
    <description></description>
    </item>

<!-- DYNAMIC INFO END HERE -->";

$text = file_get_contents('feed.xml');
str_replace('<!-- DYNAMIC INFO END HERE -->', $addMe, $text);

file_put_contents('feed.xml', $text);

?>
```

I'm trying to import a magnet link from a torrent in a XML file as a new item and scan and break the url to import the magnet title too. A magnet url has a particular syntax:
`magnet:?xt=urn:btih:MAGNET_ID&dn=MAGNET_TITLE&tr=MAGNET_TRACKERS`
where `&dn=` holds the magnet title. I'm just trying to import the entire link as a link for the rss new item and its title as title. Hope I'm clear enough..

Comment: Where are you reading the input from `$_POST`?

Comment: I'm sorry but I started with PHP for the first time just yesterday so I'm not totally sure of what do you mean with $_POST.. Are you referring to the method in the form? I thought that was just a needed syntax, not that was referring to something

Comment: Add `$link = $_POST['link'];` to the top of your PHP (just after the opening `<?php` ) and see if it does what you want it to do

Comment: no :/ tried importing a magnet url but the xml file is not edited

Comment: You'll need to do some debugging then.  Work through your code and use `$var_dump()` to see if each of your variables are being set the way you think they are.  Also turn on error reporting - `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);` at the top of your file

Comment: turned on the reporting but there is no output at the end of the process